# Using passed variable from jquery to php dynamically update fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a bunch locker numbers in a drop down list (populated from MYSQL/PHP).  I want to display the locker's combination and location when you select a locker number from the list in two input fields below on the same page.

I have used jquery to tell me which item in the list is selected dynamically.  Then I used the $.ajax() function to send that item to my server.

My problem: Can I use $.ajax() to send my variable to the same page I am on?  I have tried this and I get an error.  I am not sure how to accomplish this. My knowledge of AJAX is very minimal.

My code is as follows:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Locker Backend</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function show()
{
   $('#addlocker').toggle();
}
    function lockerSelected(sel)
       {
    var selected = (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "studentdata.php",
        data: selected,
        success: function(){
            alert(selected);
        }
       });
       }
    </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $studID = substr($url, strpos($url, "=") + 1);

    $db_handle = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pickles") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());


        mysql_select_db("lockers",$db_handle) or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE studID = $studID"); 
        ?>
    <div class="container">
      <header> <a href="#"><img src="images/headmast.png" alt="Insert Logo Here" width="686" height="180" id="Insert_logo" /></a> </header>
      <div id="data1">
      <form id ="studData" name="studData" action="update.php" medthod="post">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Student Details</legend>
          <?php
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      { 
      echo '<ol>';
       echo '<li>';
      echo '<label for=studid>Student ID</label>';
      echo '<input id=studid name=studid type=text value='.$row['studID'].'>';
      echo '</il>';
      echo '<li>';
      echo '<label for=fname>First Name</label>';
      echo '<input id=fname name=fname type=text value='.$row['firstName'].'>';
      echo '</il>';
      echo '<li>';
      echo '<label for=fname>Last Name</label>';
      echo '<input id=lname name=lname type=text value='.$row['lastName'].'>';
      echo '</il>';
      echo '<li>';
      echo '<label for=email>Email</label>';
      echo '<input id=email name=email type=text value='.$row['email'].'>';
      echo '</il>';
      echo '<li>';
      echo '<label for=progam>Program</label>';
      echo '<input id=progam name=progam type=text value='.$row['program'].'>';
      echo '</il>';
      echo '</ol>';
      $program = $row['program'];  //get name of program 
      } 
      ?>
          <input type="submit" value="Update" class="fButton"/>
        </fieldset>
      </form>

      <form id="locker" name="locker" action="" method="post" >
        <fieldset>
          <input type="button" onclick="show()" value="Add Locker"/>
          <div id="addlocker" style="display:none;"> 
          <!--
          query lockers where $program = program parsed in & student id is equal to 0 (this makes it available)
          get select list to 10
          populate select list    -->  <br/>
          <legend>Lockers Available: </legend>
          <select size="10" name="lockerSelect" multiple="yes" style="width:200px;" onChange="lockerSelected(this);">
          <?php
          $result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lockers WHERE progName = '$program' && studID = 0") or die($result1."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
          while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
      {
         echo '<option value=\"'.$row1['lockerScan'].'">'.$row1['lockerNo'].'</option>';
      }
      echo '</select>';
        echo '<br>';

        $lockerNo = $_POST['selected'];  \\doesn't work - displays error
        echo $lockerNo; \\errors out
          ?>
          </div><!--end of add locker section-->
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      </div><!--end of data1 -->
    <a href="backendhome.php" class="actionButton" style="float:left;clear:both">Search</a>  


    </div><!-- end of container-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should have another file that you send the AJAX call to.
That page should then return either json or just a string or something :) If you do this, you can make your own "codes" for what is OK and what is not.. eg like 500 = permission denied, 404 = not found, 200=ok.

Now I stole those codes from http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html ;) I often use them for different purposes too, since they stick in my brain from web servers.

If you do this, you can in your JS/JQuery check if it was in deed stored in the database :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can use :

```
function show()
{
   $('#addlocker').toggle();
}
```

Then, you should learn more about Ajax and PHP. Your call shoud be :

```
var selected = (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);

$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url: "studentdata.php",
   data: {selected: selected},
   success: function(data){
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

And in your PHP file :

```
<?php 
$select = $_POST['selected'];

//....
// Do what you have to do then return your result    

echo '<div>Send to your page !</div>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This works to send the data.  I will just have to dive into AJAX more to understand how I can use that data to talk to my mysql database and display information all on the same page..

Comment: I looked into this further and got it to work! Thanks again your input. And I am on the never ending quest to become a better coder.

Answer (score 0):

First Arrange your files. 
`js`'s is in `js` folder
`php`'s in `php` folder

best way is to assaign a seperate php page and then in js use on change event

```
$(document).on("change", "#selectfieldid", function(){
  var selected = $('#selectfieldid').val();
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "studentdata.php",
    data: selected,
    success: function(data){
        $('#addlocker').val(data); //echoed result placed here that has id addlocker

    }
   });
});
```

send those to a php page echo the result in that php.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Your line in the success:fuction(data){}); really helped me understand that I could place my information from the php page onto my current page.  Much appreciated!